# Date Range Validation making control turn into a datetime input type, just want text type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, controls

I have a Razor web page where I have a model

```
public class UploadModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string PatientID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DateRange("1000/12/01", "4010/12/16")]
    public DateTime DrawDate { get; set; }
}
public class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string DateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";
    private const string DefaultErrorMessage =
    "'{0}' must be a date between {1:d} and {2:d}.";

    public DateTime MinDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }

    public DateRangeAttribute(string minDate, string maxDate)
        : base(DefaultErrorMessage)
    {
        MinDate = ParseDate(minDate);
        MaxDate = ParseDate(maxDate);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null || !(value is DateTime))
        {
            return true;
        }
        DateTime dateValue = (DateTime)value;
        return MinDate <= dateValue && dateValue <= MaxDate;
    }
    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        ErrorMessageString,
        name, MinDate, MaxDate);
    }

    private static DateTime ParseDate(string dateValue)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue, DateFormat,
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

That does validation for the datetime

However in the view, 
when I run through all the elements in the model

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m)
```

It is creating a datetime type which creates problems because I am using jquery to do the calendar date picking since it is cross broswer.  Any way to force the datetime to become a text even with the validation class?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are writing your custom validation, why don't you change

```
public DateTime DrawDate { get; set; }
```

to a string type and adjust your validation accordingly?

Comment: thats what I ended up having to do, I was just wondering if there was some extender class that I could add in that would take care of it

Comment: You could keep the DateTime type and use something like [Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/2/2000", "3/4/2001", ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]. This way you would probably not need a custom validation class. Also, if your concern for the date being string is only for display purposes, then you could use the DisplayFormat attribute to do the conversion from DateTime to string for you, something like: [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/mm/dd}")]

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to remove the DataType attribute from the DrawDate property.